# Wrapping standard library templates for DLL export (need sanity check)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector, dllexport

I think I have a pretty good hold on the issues (different implementations, compiled binary differences, etc..) with exporting templates (vector, string, map, etc..) from the std library for a DLL (or lib) . However I find that I also dislike the use of custom vector/list/map classes and find creating an interface in classes to export their functionality to be tedious an repetitive, so I have come to the conclusion that I am just going to try and wrap said objects to the best of my ability (and accept whatever performance impact that has). That said I was wondering if you all could sanity check what I have done so far.

So this is the road I have gone down (tested with vector first). I have created a class very similar to std::vector just named vector. The intent is to include it from another file inside a namespace so the the new vector doesn't conflict with anything else. I am working on an openCl library at the moment so that's what the code is coming from.

opencl_std.h

```
#ifndef _opencl_util_opencl_std_h
#define _opencl_util_opencl_std_h

#include "opencl_util_export.h"

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#ifdef opencl_util_EXPORTS
#define OPENCL_UTIL_EXTERN
#else
#define OPENCL_UTIL_EXTERN extern
#endif

namespace cl{namespace util
{

#include "std_wrappers\vector.h"

OPENCL_UTIL_EXTERN template class OPENCL_UTIL_EXPORT ::cl::util::vector<::size_t>;

}}//namespace cl::util

#endif //_opencl_util_opencl_std_h
```

opencl.cpp

```
#include "opencl_std.h"

namespace cl{namespace util
{

#include "std_wrappers\vector.cpp"

}}//namespace cl::util
```

OPENCL_UTIL_EXPORT is the obligatory dllimport/dllexport and OPENCL_UTIL_EXTERN sets the class to extern when importing. std_wrappers\vector.h includes the declaration of the class and std_wrappers\vector.cpp includes the definition. All though the class is a template the split declaration/definition works as the class is explicitly instantiated with this call (as well as exported).

```
OPENCL_UTIL_EXTERN template class OPENCL_UTIL_EXPORT ::cl::util::vector<::size_t>;
```

std_wrappers\vector.h

```
template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
class vector_iterator;

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
class vector_const_iterator
{
public:
    typedef vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy> _Myiter;

    typedef typename _Myvec::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename _Myvec::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename _Myvec::const_pointer pointer;
    typedef typename _Myvec::const_reference reference;

    vector_const_iterator(const typename _IterTy &iter);
    vector_const_iterator(const _Myiter &right);
    vector_const_iterator(_Myiter &&right);

//    vector_const_iterator(typename _IterTy &&iter);
    ~vector_const_iterator();

    _Myiter &operator=(const _Myiter &right);
    _Myiter &operator=(_Myiter &&right);

    reference operator*() const;
    pointer operator->() const;
    _Myiter &operator++();
    _Myiter operator++(int);
    _Myiter &operator--();
    _Myiter operator--(int);
    _Myiter &operator+=(difference_type offset);
    _Myiter operator+(difference_type offset) const;
    _Myiter &operator-=(difference_type offset);
    _Myiter operator-(difference_type offset) const;
    difference_type operator-(const _Myiter &right) const;
    reference operator[](difference_type offset) const;
    bool operator==(const _Myiter &right) const;
    bool operator!=(const _Myiter &right) const;
    bool operator<(const _Myiter &right) const;
    bool operator>(const _Myiter &right) const;
    bool operator<=(const _Myiter &right) const;
    bool operator>=(const _Myiter &right) const;

    friend vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>;

private:
    typename _IterTy *_iter;
};


template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
class vector_iterator:public vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>
{
public:
    typedef vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy> _Myiter;
    typedef vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy> _Mybase;

    typedef typename _Myvec::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename _Myvec::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename _Myvec::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename _Myvec::reference reference;

    vector_iterator(const typename _IterTy &iter);
    vector_iterator(const _Myiter &right);
    vector_iterator(_Myiter &&right);
//    vector_iterator(typename _IterTy &&iter);

    _Myiter &operator=(const _Myiter &right);
    _Myiter &operator=(_Myiter &&right);

    reference operator*() const;
    pointer operator->() const;
    _Myiter &operator++();
    _Myiter operator++(int);
    _Myiter &operator--();
    _Myiter operator--(int);
    _Myiter &operator+=(difference_type offset);
    _Myiter operator+(difference_type offset) const;
    _Myiter &operator-=(difference_type offset);
    _Myiter operator-(difference_type offset) const;
    difference_type operator-(const _Mybase &right) const;
    reference operator[](difference_type offset) const;
};

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc=std::allocator<_Ty> >
class vector
{
public:
    typedef vector<_Ty, _Alloc> _Myt;
    typedef std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc> _StdTy;

    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::allocator_type allocator_type;
    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::difference_type difference_type;

    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::reference reference;
    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_pointer const_pointer;

    typedef vector_iterator<_StdTy, typename _StdTy::iterator> iterator;
    typedef vector_const_iterator<_StdTy, typename _StdTy::const_iterator> const_iterator;
    typedef vector_iterator<_StdTy, typename _StdTy::reverse_iterator> reverse_iterator;
    typedef vector_const_iterator<_StdTy, typename _StdTy::const_reverse_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
//    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::iterator iterator;
//    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_iterator const_iterator;
//    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::reverse_iterator reverse_iterator;
//    typedef typename std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_reverse_iterator const_reverse_iterator;

public:
    vector() noexcept;
    explicit vector(const _Alloc &alloc) noexcept;
    explicit vector(size_type count);
    vector(size_type count, const value_type &value);
    vector(size_type count, const value_type &value, const _Alloc &alloc=std::allocator<_Ty>);
#ifdef STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT
    template<class InputIt> vector(InputIt first, InputIt last, const _Alloc &alloc=std::allocator<_Ty>)
    { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(first, last, alloc); }
#endif//STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT
    vector(const _Myt &right);
    vector(const _Myt &right, const _Alloc &alloc);
    vector(_Myt &&right) noexcept;
    vector(_Myt &&right, const _Alloc &alloc);
#ifdef STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT
    vector(const _StdTy &right);
    vector(const _StdTy &right, const _Alloc &alloc);
    vector(_StdTy &&right) noexcept;
    vector(_StdTy &&right, const _Alloc &alloc);
#endif//STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT

    ~vector();

    vector &operator=(const _Myt &other);
    vector &operator=(_Myt &&other);
#ifdef STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT
    vector &operator=(const _StdTy &other);
    vector &operator=(_StdTy &&other);
#endif//STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT
    vector &operator=(std::initializer_list<_Ty> ilist);

    void assign(size_type count, const _Ty &value);
#ifdef STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT
    template< class InputIt> void assign(InputIt first, InputIt last) { _vector->assign(first, last); }
#endif//STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT
    void assign(std::initializer_list<_Ty> ilist);

    reference at(size_type pos);
    const_reference at(size_type pos) const;

    reference operator[](size_type pos);
    const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;

    reference front();
    const_reference front() const;

    reference back();
    const_reference back() const;

    _Ty *data() noexcept;
    const _Ty *data() const noexcept;

    iterator begin() noexcept;
    const_iterator begin() const noexcept;
    const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept;

    iterator end() noexcept;
    const_iterator end() const noexcept;
    const_iterator cend() const noexcept;

    reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept;
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const;
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept;

    reverse_iterator rend() noexcept;
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept;
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept;

    bool empty() const noexcept;
    size_type size() const noexcept;
    void reserve(size_type new_cap);
    void clear() noexcept;

    void push_back(const _Ty &value);
    void push_back(_Ty &&value);

    void resize(size_type count);
    void resize(size_type count, const value_type& value);

private:
    std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc> *_vector;
};
```

std_wrappers\vector.cpp

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//vector_const_iterator
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::vector_const_iterator(const typename _IterTy &iter) { _iter=new _IterTy(iter); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::vector_const_iterator(const _Myiter &right) { _iter=new _IterTy(*(right._iter)); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::vector_const_iterator(_Myiter &&right) { _iter=right._iter; right._iter=nullptr; }

//template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
//vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::vector_const_iterator(typename _IterTy &&iter):_iter(iter) {}

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::~vector_const_iterator(){ delete _iter; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator=(const _Myiter &right) { if(_iter==nullptr) _iter=new _IterTy(*(right._iter)); else _iter->operator=(*(right._iter)); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator=(_Myiter &&right) { if(_iter!=nullptr) delete _iter;  _iter=right._iter; right._iter=nullptr; return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::reference vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator*() const { return _iter->operator*(); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::pointer vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator->() const { return _iter->operator->(); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator++() { _iter->operator++(); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator++(int) { _iter->operator++(); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator--() { _iter->operator--(); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator--(int) { _iter->operator--(); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator+=(difference_type offset) { _iter->operator+=(offset); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator+(difference_type offset) const { _iter->operator+(offset); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator-=(difference_type offset) { _iter->operator-=(offset); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator-(difference_type offset) const { _iter->operator-(offset); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::difference_type vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator-(const _Myiter &right) const { return _iter->operator-(*right._iter); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::reference vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator[](difference_type offset) const { return _iter->operator[](offset); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
bool vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator==(const _Myiter &right) const { return _iter->operator==(*right._iter); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
bool vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator!=(const _Myiter &right) const { return _iter->operator!=(*right._iter); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
bool vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator<(const _Myiter &right) const { return _iter->operator<(*right._iter); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
bool vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator>(const _Myiter &right) const { return _iter->operator>(*right._iter); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
bool vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator<=(const _Myiter &right) const { return _iter->operator<=(*right._iter); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
bool vector_const_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator>=(const _Myiter &right) const { return _iter->operator>=(*right._iter); }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//vector_iterator
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::vector_iterator(const typename _IterTy &iter):vector_const_iterator(iter) {}

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::vector_iterator(const _Myiter &right):vector_const_iterator(right) {}

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::vector_iterator(_Myiter &&right):vector_const_iterator(right) {}

//template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
//vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::vector_iterator(typename _IterTy &&iter):vector_const_iterator(iter) {}

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator=(const _Myiter &right) { if(_iter==nullptr) _iter=new _IterTy(*(right._iter)); else _iter->operator=(*(right._iter)); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator=(_Myiter &&right) { if(_iter!=nullptr) delete _iter;  _iter=right._iter; right._iter=nullptr; return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::reference vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator*() const { return _iter->operator*(); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::pointer vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator->() const { return _iter->operator->(); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator++() { _iter->operator++(); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator++(int) { _iter->operator++(); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator--() { _iter->operator--(); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator--(int) { _iter->operator--(); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator+=(difference_type offset) { _iter->operator+=(offset); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator+(difference_type offset) const { _iter->operator+(offset); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter &vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator-=(difference_type offset) { _iter->operator-=(offset); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::_Myiter vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator-(difference_type offset) const { _iter->operator-(offset); return *this; }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::difference_type vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator-(const _Mybase &right) const { return _iter->operator-(*right._iter); }

template<class _Myvec, class _IterTy>
typename vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::reference vector_iterator<_Myvec, _IterTy>::operator[](difference_type offset) const { return _iter->operator[](offset); }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//vector
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector() noexcept { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(const _Alloc &alloc) noexcept { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(alloc); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(size_type count) { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(count); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(size_type count, const value_type &value) { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(count, value); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(size_type count, const value_type& value, const _Alloc &alloc) { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(count, value, alloc); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(const _Myt &right) { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(*(right._vector)); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(const _Myt &right, const _Alloc &alloc) { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(*(right._vector), alloc); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(_Myt &&right) noexcept { _vector=right._vector; right._vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>();  }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(_Myt &&right, const _Alloc &alloc) { _vector=right._vector; right._vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(alloc); }

#ifdef STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT
template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(const _StdTy &right) { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(right); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(const _StdTy &right, const _Alloc &alloc) { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(right, alloc); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(_StdTy &&right) noexcept { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(right); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(_StdTy &&right, const _Alloc &alloc) { _vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(right, alloc); }
#endif//STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::~vector() { delete _vector; }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc> &vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::operator=(const _Myt &other) { _vector->operator=(*(other._vector)); return *this;}

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc> &vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::operator=(_Myt &&other) { delete _vector; _vector=other._vector; other._vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(); return *this; }

#ifdef STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT
template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc> &vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::operator=(const _StdTy &other) { _vector->operator=(other); return *this; }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc> &vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::operator=(_StdTy &&other) { _vector->operator=(other); return *this; }
#endif//STD_WRAPPER_EXPORT

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc> &vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::operator=(std::initializer_list<_Ty> ilist) { _vector->operator=(ilist); return *this; }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
void vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::assign(size_type count, const _Ty &value) { _vector->assign(count, value); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
void vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::assign(std::initializer_list<_Ty> ilist) { _vector->assign(ilist); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::reference vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::at(size_type pos) { return _vector->at(pos); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_reference vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::at(size_type pos) const { return _vector->at(pos); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::reference vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::operator[](size_type pos) { return _vector->operator[](pos); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_reference vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::operator[](size_type pos) const { return _vector->operator[](pos); };

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::reference vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::front() { return _vector->front(); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_reference vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::front() const { return _vector->front(); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::reference vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::back() { return _vector->back(); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_reference vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::back() const { return _vector->back(); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
_Ty *vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::data() noexcept { return _vector->data(); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
const _Ty *vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::data() const noexcept { return _vector->data(); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::begin() noexcept { return iterator(_vector->begin()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::begin() const noexcept { return const_iterator(_vector->cbegin()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::cbegin() const noexcept { return const_iterator(_vector->cbegin()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::end() noexcept { return iterator(_vector->end()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::end() const noexcept { return const_iterator(_vector->cend()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::cend() const noexcept { return const_iterator(_vector->cend()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::reverse_iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::rbegin() noexcept { return reverse_iterator(_vector->rbegin()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_reverse_iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::rbegin() const { return const_reverse_iterator(_vector->crbegin()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_reverse_iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::crbegin() const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator(_vector->crbegin()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::reverse_iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::rend() noexcept { return reverse_iterator(_vector->rend()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_reverse_iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::rend() const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator(_vector->crend()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::const_reverse_iterator vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::crend() const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator(_vector->crend()); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
bool vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::empty() const noexcept { return _vector->empty(); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
typename vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::size_type vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::size() const noexcept { return _vector->size(); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
void vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::reserve(size_type new_cap) { _vector->reserve(new_cap); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
void vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::clear() noexcept { _vector->clear(); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
void vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Ty &value) { _vector->push_back(value); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
void vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back(_Ty &&value) { _vector->push_back(value); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
void vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::resize(size_type count) { _vector->resize(count); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
void vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::resize(size_type count, const value_type& value) { _vector->resize(count, value); }
```

I left out a few functions as I don't believe I can make them work (basically any function that has its own template)

```
template< class InputIt > vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
template< class InputIt > void assign( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

and I had to take some care with the rvalue reference function but I think I got it correct.

```
template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(vector<_Ty, _Alloc> &&right) noexcept { _vector=right._vector; right._vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>();  }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector(vector<_Ty, _Alloc> &&right, const _Alloc &alloc) { _vector=right._vector; right._vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(alloc); }

template<class _Ty, class _Alloc>
vector<_Ty, _Alloc> &vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::operator=(vector<_Ty, _Alloc> &&other) { delete _vector; _vector=other._vector; other._vector=new std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>(); return *this; }
```

I have compiled and ran this all in VS2015 and everything seems kosher (granted thats not saying much for the rest of the compilers). I am getting a C4661 warning on the explicit template instantiation.

```
opencl_std.h(21): warning C4661: 'void cl::util::vector<std::size_t,std::allocator<std::_Ty>>::resize(unsigned __int64)': no suitable definition provided for explicit template instantiation request
```

but I think that it is purely a warning as it is defined just not before the instantiation happens. I expected the C4251 warning from this line,

```
std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc> *_vector;
```

but I didn't see one, considering it is a pointer the compiled versions should agree on its size anyway. Using cl::util::vector<::size_t> from the library works fine. I have even tried to use cl::util::vector<::int> and got link warnings as I expected (as it was never instantiated). I plan to do this with some of the other templates, list, map, unordered_map, string, etc... just looking for a check if I missed something.

**Edit**
added this to a [github repo](https://github.com/caseymcc/std_wrappers) and will update it as I complete wrappers

Comment: this might be better suited to the code review stack exchange:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you worry about `vector`, `vector::iterator` might have same issue.

Comment: You should avoid too to include `<vector>` in your exposed header (pimpl idiom may allow to hides `std::vector`.).

Comment: To be honest the entire question content makes little sense to me. It is almost like you are writing `std::vector` wrapper template with definition in translation unit exporting particular specialization of this template to avoid dealing with `std::vector` exposed through library public interface hoping that this will improve library compatibility somehow.

Comment: @VTT not sure if I am suppose to be taking that with sarcasm or not but I got a laugh either way as that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @YoungJohn is there a way to move it, I did not know codereview existed.

Comment: @Jarod42 you are right the compiler knows that vector::iterator is the same as std::vector::iterator and is more than happy to allow it to be used that way. Guess I can't use the typedef shortcuts.

Comment: I mean that for example, `std::vector::iterator` implementation may differs and you have the same issue as sharing `std::vector`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah got that, was just commenting that I wasn't going to get away with using std::vectors iterator. Trying to find away around it and not looking good. I didn't want to replace the iterator (also the reason I didn't go with pimpl) as I was hoping to keep the same performance as std::vector's iterator. If I replace it with a wrapper every call to the iterator is going to take a hit. Thinking of just inheriting the std::vector iterator, not sure of the implications just yet.

Comment: @user1302439 I think a moderator can migrate it, but I don't actually know the process for that.

Comment: The whole idea does not make much sense... Either, you should ensure that you use compatible compilers and options on both side or you should use a simplified interface across DLL boundaries... or you should put all code in the same DLL. In any case, it is a bad idea to have such strong coupling...

Comment: I can't say its the best idea or not but looking at things from an average developer I think it makes sense. From what I read (whether this actually happens or not) some thing as simple as -02 to -03 can alter the memory footprint (or compiled code) enough to cause subtle issues. So the general idea is don't use standard templates in library interfaces. However if I want to pass something like a vector across that interface then my choice is the create a vector like object and pass that. Then the question is why recreate something that already exists. As far as I can tell this gives me both.